# How to handle node click in PyViz/datashader network samples?

Tags: python, graph, callback, datashader, pyviz

I looked at [datashader/Networks](https://datashader.org/user_guide/Networks.html) and [PyViz/network_packets](https://examples.pyviz.org/network_packets/network_packets.html#network-packets-gallery-network-packets) (which also uses datashader). I want to get a callback to python code on node selection (call a function on a node id, i.e. `fun(node_id)`). How can this be done in PyViz/datashader?

Comment: See https://examples.pyviz.org/uk_researchers/ , which shows how to overlay a clickable decimated subset of nodes onto a much larger datashader-rendered network plot. If that works for you, please then post it as the answer to your question! Also note that Datashader is part of HoloViz.org, while PyViz covers all viz tools in Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made a real effort to implement it with datashader or PyViz, however, from how you phrase the question it seems that It's more important to you to get a callback on the networks graph node than the specific technology.

This is a solution for a callback on `node_id` based on the `maccdc2012_edges` network graph, using NetworkX which is very similar to the technologies specified.

Declared `my_callback(node_id)` callback, up to your requirements, which is triggered when clicking on a specific node.

I've limited to the first 10 rows so it can be seen clearly and added scroll zoom for your convenience.

```
import pandas as pd

import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import graphistry
from pylab import *

class AnnoteFinder:  # thanks to http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Interactive_Plotting
    """
    callback for matplotlib to visit a node (display an annotation) when points are clicked on.  The
    point which is closest to the click and within xtol and ytol is identified.
    """
    def __init__(self, xdata, ydata, annotes, callback = None, threshold=None, axis=None, xtol=None, ytol=None):
        self.data = list(zip(xdata, ydata, annotes))
        if xtol is None: xtol = ((max(xdata) - min(xdata))/float(len(xdata)))/2
        if ytol is None: ytol = ((max(ydata) - min(ydata))/float(len(ydata)))/2
        self.xtol = xtol
        self.ytol = ytol
        if axis is None: axis = gca()
        self.axis= axis
        self.drawnAnnotations = {}
        self.links = []
        self.callback = callback
        self.threshold = threshold if threshold else 1.0e-3

    def __call__(self, event):
        if event.inaxes:
            clickX = event.xdata
            clickY = event.ydata
            if self.axis is None or self.axis==event.inaxes:
                annotes = []
                smallest_x_dist = float('inf')
                smallest_y_dist = float('inf')
                for x,y,a in self.data:
                    if abs(clickX-x)<=smallest_x_dist and abs(clickY-y)<=smallest_y_dist :
                        dx, dy = x - clickX, y - clickY
                        annotes.append((dx*dx+dy*dy,x,y, a) )
                        smallest_x_dist=abs(clickX-x)
                        smallest_y_dist=abs(clickY-y)
                if annotes:
                    annotes.sort() # to select the nearest node
                    distance, x, y, annote = annotes[0]
                    print(distance)
                    if distance < self.threshold:
                        if self.callback:
                            self.callback(annote)

# https://notebooks.azure.com/seanreed1111/projects/PYVIZ1/html/data/maccdc2012_edges.parq
df = pd.read_parquet('maccdc2012_edges.parq').head(10)

def my_callback(node_id):
    print(f'Clicked {node_id}')

# Build your graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'source', 'target')
pos = nx.spring_layout(G,k=0.1, iterations=20)  # the layout gives us the nodes position x,y,annotes=[],[],[] for key in pos:
x, y, annotes = [], [], []
for key in pos:
    d = pos[key]
    annotes.append(key)
    x.append(d[0])
    y.append(d[1])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

nx.draw(G, pos, font_size=6, node_color='skyblue', edge_color='#BB0000', width=0.5, node_size=200, with_labels=True)


af = AnnoteFinder(x, y, annotes, my_callback)
connect('button_press_event', af)

class ZoomPan:
    def __init__(self):
        self.press = None
        self.cur_xlim = None
        self.cur_ylim = None
        self.x0 = None
        self.y0 = None
        self.x1 = None
        self.y1 = None
        self.xpress = None
        self.ypress = None


    def zoom_factory(self, ax, base_scale = 2.):
        def zoom(event):
            cur_xlim = ax.get_xlim()
            cur_ylim = ax.get_ylim()

            xdata = event.xdata # get event x location
            ydata = event.ydata # get event y location

            if event.button == 'down':
                # deal with zoom in
                scale_factor = 1 / base_scale
            elif event.button == 'up':
                # deal with zoom out
                scale_factor = base_scale
            else:
                # deal with something that should never happen
                scale_factor = 1
                print(event.button)

            new_width = (cur_xlim[1] - cur_xlim[0]) * scale_factor
            new_height = (cur_ylim[1] - cur_ylim[0]) * scale_factor

            relx = (cur_xlim[1] - xdata)/(cur_xlim[1] - cur_xlim[0])
            rely = (cur_ylim[1] - ydata)/(cur_ylim[1] - cur_ylim[0])

            ax.set_xlim([xdata - new_width * (1-relx), xdata + new_width * (relx)])
            ax.set_ylim([ydata - new_height * (1-rely), ydata + new_height * (rely)])
            ax.figure.canvas.draw()

        fig = ax.get_figure() # get the figure of interest
        fig.canvas.mpl_connect('scroll_event', zoom)

        return zoom

    def pan_factory(self, ax):
        def onPress(event):
            if event.inaxes != ax: return
            self.cur_xlim = ax.get_xlim()
            self.cur_ylim = ax.get_ylim()
            self.press = self.x0, self.y0, event.xdata, event.ydata
            self.x0, self.y0, self.xpress, self.ypress = self.press

        def onRelease(event):
            self.press = None
            ax.figure.canvas.draw()

        def onMotion(event):
            if self.press is None: return
            if event.inaxes != ax: return
            dx = event.xdata - self.xpress
            dy = event.ydata - self.ypress
            self.cur_xlim -= dx
            self.cur_ylim -= dy
            ax.set_xlim(self.cur_xlim)
            ax.set_ylim(self.cur_ylim)

            ax.figure.canvas.draw()

        fig = ax.get_figure() # get the figure of interest

        # attach the call back
        fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',onPress)
        fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event',onRelease)
        fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event',onMotion)

        #return the function
        return onMotion

scale = 1.1
zp = ZoomPan()
figZoom = zp.zoom_factory(ax, base_scale = scale)
figPan = zp.pan_factory(ax)

show()
```

Disclaimer: This solution is an adjustment based on these threads: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894985/how-to-make-a-click-able-graph-by-networkx) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551049/matplotlib-plot-zooming-with-scroll-wheel).